# Resque waiting for job forever

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

Important note: this is the first time I'm using Resque and Redis.

I created this task:

```
class SimpleTask
  @queue=:simple

  def self.perform(msg)
    puts ":("
  end

end
```

I scheduled 100 of them using rails console:

```
irb(main):015:0> (0..100).each {|n| Resque.enqueue(SimpleTask,'come on!') }
=> 0..100
irb(main):016:0> Resque.info
=> {:pending=>101, :processed=>0, :queues=>1, :workers=>0, :working=>0, :failed=>0, :servers=>["redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"], :environment=>"development"}
irb(main):017:0> Resque.peek('simple')
=> {"class"=>"SimpleTask", "args"=>["come on!"]}
```

When I launch worker using this command:

```
rake environment resque:work
```

It falls into inifinite loop:

```
*** Starting worker home-pc:7972:'simple'
*** Registered signals
*** Checking 'simple'
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.23.0: Waiting for 'simple'
*** Checking 'simple'
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.23.0: Waiting for 'simple'
*** Checking 'simple'
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.23.0: Waiting for 'simple'
*** Checking 'simple'
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.23.0: Waiting for 'simple'
*** Checking 'simple'
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.23.0: Waiting for 'simple'
*** Checking 'simple'
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.23.0: Waiting for 'simple'
```

Web interface shows that there is one worker "Waiting for a job...". It also shows 101 jobs pending in 'simple' queue.

What is wrong with my setup?

Also, I'm running all this on Windows, using Redis port. Redis seems to work fine, at least Resque has all of the information it stores in Redis.

Comment: erm, i think that you need to tell the worker which queue to use: ```QUEUE=simple rake resque:work```

Comment: Sorry, it is assumed set, resque won't start without it. Output shows that it knows, that 'simple' is the queue I'm launching.

Comment: @Anton Who did you mange to do that `resque` in windows AFAIK fork is not supported in windows just on your `irb` do this `Kernel.fork` see if support also check [this](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L254-L272) See if you getting the `NotImplementedError` error